# React not communicating with node server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, server

In order to complete this project, I need to get my client to communicate with my server. 
What I want : The '/auth' should just return a string "Authorize".
What I receive : a string copy of all the mark-up in my index.html.

Front, using reactJS:

```
 authorize()
  {
      fetch('/auth')
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(data=>{
            console.log('auth'+data)
        })
        .catch(err => err);
  }

  async componentDidMount()
  {
      try
      {       
        this.authorize();
      }
      catch(e)
      {
          console.log(e);
      }
  }
```

Backend:

```
 var createError = require('http-errors');
    var express = require('express');
    var path = require('path');
    var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
    var logger = require('morgan');
    var cors = require("cors");

    const dotenv = require('dotenv');
    dotenv.config();

    const jwt = require('express-jwt');
    const jwksRsa = require('jwks-rsa');

    var indexRouter = require("./routes/index");
    var authRouter = require("./routes/auth");

    var app = express();
    app.use(cors());

    // view engine setup
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');

    app.use(logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

    app.use('/', indexRouter);
    app.use('/auth', authRouter);
```

Router example:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) 
{ 
  res.send("router/index");
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1):

`app.use` will automatically match all routes that extend the base route, in your case `/`, which is why all requests to `/*` will be handled by your `indexRouter`. See http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html for further details.

One way to solve this, is to change the order:

```
app.use('/auth', authRouter);
app.use('/', indexRouter);
```

Comment: Changing their use order did not fix this. I tried swapping the require order, too.

Comment: Can you add the contents of the routers?

Comment: var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();

router.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
    res.send("Authorize"); 
});

module.exports = router;

I don't know if I can add code format to comments?

Comment: Just edit your question and it add it there. Also add the code of the `indexRouter`, please.

Comment: Awesome help! I've put it at the bottom of the main post

Comment: Weird, this acutally looks ok with the routers you have set up .. maybe someone else can help out, sorry :)

Comment: In this case, my fetch needed the full URL to connect (ie. http://localhost:9000/auth)